# SWT - wrap text in table cells

Tags: java, swt, word-wrap

I am trying to find a way to wrap text in table cells using SWT, but
I'm stuck. Does anybody know of a way to do it? Or is there a
different way to approach the problem? Basically, I have 12 columns: 
6 of them are check boxes, and remaining are text fields only.

The text in the columns should be wrap automatically if the length of the size 
exceeds the width of the column.

Please help me

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014765/simultaneously-right-align-and-wrap-text-in-an-swt-label-in-linux-gnome

Comment: post some code which you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

SWT `Table` does not support automatic line wrapping. You can however insert newline characters yourself. See the following links for further reference:

- [Bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19496)
- [TableItem does not support mnemonics, wrapping, or the SWT.WRAP style.](http://book.javanb.com/swt-the-standard-widget-toolkit/ch09lev1sec2.html)
- [multiline feature or wrap text feature in jface tableviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355693/multiline-feature-or-wrap-text-feature-in-jface-tableviewer)
- [Java2s example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/MultilineTablecell.htm)

Comment: @user2642221 So did you solve your problem? If so, please post it as an answer. Then others can use your solution if they are having the same issue.